# Problem with geom_raster size vector cannot be allocated

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, r-sf, r-raster

I'm astonished by the recurrent problem of  `size vector cannot be allocated` in `geom_raster` function. This problem happens with small data set and in my case 1559 observations. I try to do:

```
# Read the raster in data frame format
ras_df<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/myraster_df.csv")
str(ras_df)
#'data.frame':  1559 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ cc       : num  65 85.6 82.7 85.6 89.4 ...
# $ longitude: num  -50.6 -50.6 -50.6 -50.6 -50.6 ...
# $ latitude : num  -24.2 -24.2 -24.2 -24.2 -24.2 ...

# Representation
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = ras_df , aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = cc)) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(name="Canopy cover",colours = rev(terrain.colors(100)))+
  xlab("longitude") + ylab("latitude") +
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_quickmap() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
text=element_text(size=16,  family="serif"),legend.position="bottom")
#
#
#Error: 20254.0 Gb size vector cannot be allocated
```

But if I use the normal `plot()` function this does not occur, but I look for a more beautiful representation like `ggplot2` output. And several posts with some solutions don't work very well for me (eg. `SpatialPixelsDataFrame` conversion and tolerance control).

Please, any ideas for I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning that came with the error was informative

> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: Raster pixels are placed at uneven horizontal intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead.
> 2: Raster pixels are placed at uneven vertical intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead.

This happen when the data have spurious precision, so `geom_raster` tries to make a very fine grid which uses insane amounts of memory.

The solution is simply to round the data to an appropriate amount of precision.

```
library(tidyverse)
ras_df <- ras_df %>% mutate(across(c(latitude, longitude), round, digits = 4))
```

The plot then works fine.

Comment: Nice @Richard Telford!!