# ggplot: "No non-missing arguments to min/max; returning Inf"

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-raster, gratia

I'm attempting to recreate this plot (my version: lat/lon by year), but keep getting these warnings after running the ggplot code:

[image]

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: `stat_contour()`: Zero contours were generated
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
...
43: `stat_contour()`: Zero contours were generated
44: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
45: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
46: Raster pixels are placed at uneven horizontal intervals and will be shifted
ℹ Consider using `geom_tile()` instead.
```

I thought [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67724203/problem-with-geom-raster-size-vector-cannot-be-allocated) would remove one of the warnings, but it persists...

```
> dput(sms2[1:5,])
structure(list(smooth = c("ti(CYR,Longitude,Latitude)", "ti(CYR,Longitude,Latitude)", 
"ti(CYR,Longitude,Latitude)", "ti(CYR,Longitude,Latitude)", "ti(CYR,Longitude,Latitude)"
), type = c("Tensor product int.", "Tensor product int.", "Tensor product int.", 
"Tensor product int.", "Tensor product int."), by = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    est = c(0.117025782747128, 0.113479508095921, 0.0933787695695134, 
    0.0895995641580288, 0.0755531029189105), se = c(0.185913143579915, 
    0.181005541009251, 0.152005779645215, 0.142402142342131, 
    0.119622723237741), CYR = c(2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L
    ), Longitude = c(-80.3026, -80.3034, -80.3075, -80.3076, 
    -80.31), Latitude = c(25.5694, 25.5684, 25.5618, 25.558, 
    25.5519)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("smooth_estimates", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), tensor_term_order = list(`ti(CYR,Longitude,Latitude)` = c("Longitude", 
"Latitude", "CYR")))

est_lim <- c(-1, 1) * max(abs(sms2[["est"]]), na.rm = TRUE)

sms2 |> 
  mutate(fCYR = factor(CYR)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = est, group = fCYR)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = est, group = fCYR)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = est, group = fCYR, fill = NULL), colour = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~ fCYR) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu", type = "div") +
  expand_limits(fill = est_lim)
```

Resultant plot

[image]

Comment: There is a lot to unpack in this question, and your data is password protected. Please start by providing just the data that is fed into the plot code where the problem occurs. Additionally, your code seems out of order? If you think there is an error in the data compilation causing your issue it would be best to start with the raw data `sms` then provide data manipulation code (`sms2`) followed by the plot code.

Comment: If it's a very large dataset you should subset it to a point where all necessary information is there but it doesn't contain every row. `dput(sms[1:10,])` will provide the first 10 rows of data

Comment: I tried adding the original data, but got flagged for my question being was mostly code. My fix to the error I got was just to round Lat/Lon. Thanks for verifying my data was protected, 5 rows of data was the best I could do here.

Comment: Still a few issues, do us and yourself a favor and clear your workspace and try to run just the code you provide in the example to see if it works. Right now I see two issues: 1) you never created `est_lim`, and 2)should the last line for the plot be `expand_limits(aes(fill = est_lim))`?

Comment: I don't think so, I get this error with that change: Error in as.name(x) : attempt to use zero-length variable name

Comment: You're right, what is `est_lim`? Try the clear workspace, then copy and paste the code you posted and run it trick

Comment: I've added "est_lim" back in (removed it by mistake).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252608/discussion-between-nate-and-dandrews).

Answer (score 2):

A start...it seems you need to interpolate to create a full grid per this site: https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-warning-stat-contour-zero-contours-were-generated/111020/2

Here's a simple start:

```
a <- sms2$Latitude
b <- sms2$Longitude
d <- expand.grid(a,b)
d$z <- rep(sms2$est)
d
ggplot(data = d, aes(Var1, Var2, z = z)) + geom_contour_filled()
```